# Remove the Server header from IIS 10 403 Forbidden error page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

We have the ASP.NET MVC application which hosted on IIS 10. In order to close vulnerability `Information disclosure` we need to remove all the headers which disclosures web server's information, like `Server`, `X-Powered-By`, etc.

We have enabled all the options to remove this headers, but when we request some unexisting page, like `/Controller/Action"` we got 403 Forbidden error page with Server header.

I already tried URL Rewrite rules, editing registry, adding some properties to web.config, but it doesn't work.

How can I remove it?

Comment: May I know how did you remove the `server` header currently ?

Comment: Hi, may I know if the solution provided below works ? And by the way, you can also try with refresh the browser with "ctrl + F5" or new inprivate window to escape cache.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that enabled all the options to remove the header, so I think you may use the configuration as below in your `web.config`.

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering removeServerHeader="true" />
</security>
```

Apart from this, you can also use url rewrite to remove the `server` header. Url rewrite can filter all of the response and remove the header which you specified to remove. You can refer to the steps below:

**1.** Install "[url rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)" extension.

**2.** Open your IIS manager, and double click "url rewrite" and click "View Server Variables"
[image]

**3.** Click "Add" button to add a variable named "RESPONSE_SERVER".

[image]

**4.** Go back to "url rewrite" and add a outbound rule.

[image]

**5.** Then create the rule with the information as below.

[image]

[image]

After create this rule, we can filter all of the outbound response and remove the `server` header. You can also refer to [this document](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/remove-unwanted-http-response-headers/ba-p/369710) about this solution.